# Android:Put an image over another image

Tags: android, view, android-imageview

I have three `ImageViews` and i want 1 `ImageView` to be in the background and the other 2 images should be laying on that one. I cannot use any other view because the image is downloaded in the image form that cannot be set as `Linear` or `Relative` layout background.

FIRST IMAGE

[image]

THIS IS THE SECOND IMAGE WHAT I WANT ACTUALLY

[image]

Comment: Use `FrameLayout` for your requirement

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try as below xml layout...

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dip"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dip"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

To **overlap** views or **block a display area for a single item**  Frame layout([here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)) can be used.

you can use

```
     <FrameLayout 
        android:layout_width="..."
        android:layout_height="..."
        android:background="Image1"
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="..."
            android:layout_height="..."
            android:background="image2">
         <ImageView
            android:layout_width="..."
            android:layout_height="..."
            android:background="image3">   
     </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the easiest way I've found to merge more than one image at one.
This is very helpful if we want share merged file.

```
Resources r = getResources();    
Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[3];
layers[0] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.image3);
layers[1] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.image1);
layers[2] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.image2);

LayerDrawable layerDrawable= new LayerDrawable(layers);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
// align image1 over image3
layerDrawable.setLayerGravity(1, Gravity.TOP);
layerDrawable.setLayerInsetTop(1, 250);

// align image2 over image3
layerDrawable.setLayerGravity(2, Gravity.BOTTOM);
layerDrawable.setLayerInsetBottom(2, 250);
}
 // both image1 & 2 placed over image3 in layerDrawable.
imageView.setImageDrawable(layerDrawable);
```

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

First use a relativie layout in that add image view with width and height set as match parent.Then take second image view alignParentTop property true for that and similarly for third imageview align its property parentbottom true with width and height set as wrap content

Answer (score 0):

You can use layer-list make layers.xml in your drawable
Something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<item>
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/img1"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
</item>
<item>
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/img2"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
</item>
</layer-list>
```